# Angular AsyncValidator does not work as I wanted

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, angular-validation, angular-validator

This is not my first time using `AsyncValidator` but this time I'm trying to create something more complicated. I am building a bank website. In my project, each user has multiple accounts.

I have two input areas in my form:

- Input-1 takes the username.
- Input-2 takes account number.

I want to take the username from Input-1 and find the accounts the user has, and I want to give an error to Input-2 if the account number in Input-2 is not one of the user's accounts.

Angular V8

Like in this photo...

[image]

This is the validator:

```js
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AsyncValidator, ValidationErrors, AbstractControl, NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, Subscription, of } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from '../service/user.service';
import { map, take, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AccountService } from '../service/account.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[transferAccountid]',
  providers: [{ provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, useExisting: TransferAccountidValidatorDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class TransferAccountidValidatorDirective implements AsyncValidator {
  @Input('transferAccountid') controlUsername: string;

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private accountService: AccountService) { }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    const username = c.root.get(this.controlUsername);
    let id: number;

    if (username) {
      return this.userService.getUserByUsername(username.value).pipe(
        switchMap(user => {
          if (user[0] != null) {
            id =  user[0].id;
            return this.accountService.getAccountsByUser(id)
              .pipe(
                map(accounts => {
                  return accounts.map(account => {
                    console.log("AccountId: " ,account.id);
                    return account.id === c.value ? null : {'transferAccountid': true}
                  })
                })
              );
          } else { return new Observable<null>(); }
        })
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Here is the  [Stackblitz Link...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7khit1)

Comment: could you provide a stackblitz with this example on it?

Comment: It's gonna be hard to do it because I am using a local database. But I will try my best

Comment: @Shorbagy Sorry it took me a bit to fake Web API. I hope you have time to take a look at it. 
here is the link.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7khit1
It only works when type "akoksal" as the username in Input-1. Thanks.

Comment: I have solved your problem in this fork https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdvxsp

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for the past couple of days. Thank you!!

Comment: Your're Welcome! if you can up vote as well it will be good!

Comment: @Shorbagy I want to but I couldn't find vote up button :( How do I do it? Sorry I am new here.